# Send variable to PHP using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got a variable that I want to send to my PHP code that is on top of the code but I keep getting an error and `undefined`. `dTotaal` is the variable name and it contains a number. All this code is in the same page, so i am posting to the same page.

```
$('#emailVerzenden').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "content.php",
        type: "post",
        data: ({
            totaal: dTotaal
        }),
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('Data saved: ' + msg);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("couldnt be sent " + error); 
        }
    });
```

On top of my page I've got this code. I'm not sure if it's correct, I am new at this.

```
if(isset($_POST['emailVerzenden']))
{
    $totaal = $_POST['totaal'];
    var_dump($totaal);
}
```

What I wanted was to put the value of the `totaal` data in `$totaal` but that is not working. The data is not being sent. I keep getting the error `alert()`.

Comment: first define variable dTotaal.

Comment: If you're getting the error `alert()` it means the server side code is not returning a `200 OK` response. Check the network tab of the console to see exactly what the response and error is. Also note that the string concatenation operator in JS is `+`, not `.` as you're using in the `error` handler.

Comment: @SantoshPatel Its Defined it has a value from a math a did in Jquery. when i Alert it, it works i am also using it as output as price, the only thing is that it doesnt post.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Never used the Network tab before i was checking it out but can you give me a clue for what i should be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, you are checking the presence of a variable to use another. For me it should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['totaal']))
{
$totaal= $_POST['totaal'];
var_dump($totaal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track but seperate `PHP` codes with `jQuery` codes then you will have full control of processing data asynchronously.

**index.php**

```
  $('#emailVerzenden').click(function()
        {
            $.ajax
            ({
                url: "content.php",
                type: "post",
                data:{totaal: dTotaal},
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    alert('Data saved: ' + msg);
                },
                error: function(error)
                {
                    alert("couldnt be sent ".error); 
                }
            });
```

And in your php file  first check whether `$_POST` data is set

**content.php**

```
 if(isset($_POST))
  { 
    $totaal= $_POST['totaal'];
   var_dump($totaal);
 }
```

Comment: Both of my code are in the same file content.php , PHP on top and Jquery on the bottom.

Comment: I get it but remove PHP codes on top of your file and put it in a different file `[newfile.php]`. Don't forget to change the `url` in jquery ajax to `url: "newfile.php",`

Comment: did but its still the same, the problem is at the ajax code. It doesnt post anything at all i keep getting the error alert().

Answer (score 0):

Mention your data which you wanna send in html & give it an ID.

```
 <div id="total"> HERE COMES THE VARIABLE YOU WISH TO SEND </div>
```

Then pick up the data in that `<div>` by its ID `document.getElementById('total').value` like below:

```
var total=document.getElementById('total').value;

<script> var total=document.getElementById('total').value;  
  $.post('content.php',
        {'total':total},
        function(response){ 
            if(response == 'YES'){}
          });
</script>
```

Hope this will resolve your problem. Good Luck!

Comment: What i am doing its a math and i want to send the result as a variable to PHP when i alert it i get the value 600 but when i try to send it , it doesnt work.

Comment: send the value into a variable like `var total='your result'` and send it like i've sent it.

Comment: Yeah thats what i was trying to tell you i got the value/result in dTotaal. soo dTotaal is the value.

Comment: `$.post('content.php',
        {'dTotaal':dTotaal},
        function(response){ 
            if(response == 'YES'){}
          }); `                        you will get this variable in controller by `$this->input->post('dTotaal');`

Answer (score 0):

Kind of look like i didnt use preventDefault() thats why it wasnt working.

```
$('#emailVerzenden').click(function(e)
        {
            cms=$('#sCms').val();
            templates= $('#templates').val();
            onderdelen = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value; 
}).get();
            email = $('#email').val();
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",  
                url:"test.php", 
                data:{postEmail : email,postOnderdelen : onderdelen,postCms : cms,postTotaal : postTotaal, postTemplates : templates}, 
                success: function(rs)   
                {
                    alert("Data saved:" + rs);
                },
                error: function(error)
                {
                    alert("couldnt be sent" + error); 
                }
            }); 
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
```